# Child window with maximize and close buttons

Tags: javafx-2, parent-child

Still working on learning here ... I'm trying to make an application window (stage) into which I can call child windows. The parent naturally comes with minimize, maximize and close (x) buttons, but when I add a child window I can't move or resize the child, and it does not have the standard three buttons.

Here's code I've been toying with:

```
// Stage ventasStage = new Stage(); // originally the child was stand alone and had the standard 3 buttons
AnchorPane ventas = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Punto_de_Venta.class.getResource("VentasGUI.fxml"));
//    Scene ventasScene = new Scene(ventas); //"stage" and "scene" removed to add "getChildren"
home.getChildren().add(ventas);
```

The getChildren gets my new window to be part of the parent scene, but I cannot get the 3 standard buttons. I assume the buttons are added to a Stage and NOT to an AnchorPane (which is what getChildren is getting here) but getChildren can't be used with a Stage, right? So how do I make a parent with interchangeable children where each child is moveable, resizable and has the standard three buttons (minimize, maximize and close)?

Answer (score 0):

Three buttons correspond to a standart Window (it is provided by OS), and it is Stage. Scene - is an object, which corresponds to scene graph and is a propeerty of stage. So use stage.setScene(..) to set Scene to Stage. Stene has a root node (usually, some kind of layout). And it seems for me, that you should use Scene.setRoot(...) method.

BTW, about Stage: you can use stage.init...() to use different decoration schemas, and different types of modality.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the info. However, I have already tried to import the Stage as a child to the parent stage (primaryStage), but the getChildren.add() does not allow me to call a Stage (or a Scene). Anyone have any other suggestions how I can add a stage, scene or anchorpane as a child but have that child resizable, moveable and have the standard three buttons?

Comment: Three buttons is a property of Window only. You cannot apply getChildren().add() to Windows anyhow. But you can call getChildren().add() on a root of scene of stage...